# ios - should I have app icons named icon-114@2x.png

Tags: ios

I am working on some app icons and my understanding is that if the standard app icon is 57x57, then the retina display version of it is 114x114

But I am coming across some things that are named like this:

```
icon-114@2x.png
```

Is that a mistake? Or should that be there?

Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't actually matter in case of the icons , the @2x at the end actually tells the app which is high quality and which is not. so basically if you want to create an image you should have let's say image.png and image@2x.png so the app can use the resource compatible with the screen resolution.

Comment: @soryngod: You do have to register the file names (if you use non-defaults) somewhere, though, right?

Comment: @soryngod thanks. So is the 2x image just a double-dimension of the original? Then why have the 57 and 144 requirements?

Comment: Of course you have to add it , and you can in the Project Summary, and  the 57 is used for Non-Retina Display and 114 is used for Retina Display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add icons do this...

1. Put all your different icon images onto your desktop (or some folder that isn't part of the project).
2. Delete any icon images from your project.
3. Go to the project build summary page.
4. Drag each image to its respective slot.

Done.

You don't need to worry about names or anything. Xcode will rename them for you and copy them into your project.

Comment: thanks, so just to clarify...no need for the 2x images, right?

Comment: Just call them "smallIcon", "largeIcon", etc... Or even "Bob", "Richard", etc... it doesn't matter. When you do it this way it will rename them to "icon", "icon@2x" or whatever. Either way, don't worry about the names. As long as you follow these steps it will work.

Comment: he was asking why the need for @2x images , so you can edit your response to answer the question correctly.

Comment: The answer is, the names are irrelevant. As long as you add them to the project this way then don't worry about the names.